# Print keyvalue on single line for all elements in an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I'm trying to get the list of tags from an EC2 instance, and apply those tags to all the attached volumes of that instance, like so:

```
# Get the tags of the instance (filter out tags containing :aws:, since those are tags that AWS applies and they are NOT ours):
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=${instance_id}" --region us-west-2 | jq '[ .Tags[] | select( .Key | contains(":aws:") | not ) ]'

# That command produces this output:
[
  {
    "ResourceType": "instance",
    "ResourceId": "i-0f1da295d8343635b",
    "Value": "tester",
    "Key": "Name"
  },
  {
    "ResourceType": "instance",
    "ResourceId": "i-0f1da295d8343635b",
    "Value": "test_env",
    "Key": "environment"
  },
  {
    "ResourceType": "instance",
    "ResourceId": "i-0f1da295d8343635b",
    "Value": "ui_tester",
    "Key": "role"
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, the create-tags api command takes a form of:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources vol-076317f0fd49cb024 vol-0e91c84611369fc3f \
 --tags Key=role,Value=ui_tester Key=environment,Value=test_env Key=Name,Value=tester
```

How do I use jq to convert that array of Key/Values into a single line like so:

```
Key=role,Value=ui_tester Key=environment,Value=test_env Key=Name,Value=tester
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your jq filter:

```
[.Tags[] | select(.Key | contains(":aws:") | not) | "Key=\(.Key),Value=\(.Value)"] | join(" ")
```